# Meshlab crashes because of undefined symbol

Tags: linux, undefined-symbol, meshlab

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit, Meshlab is crashing when I apply "Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction" plugin. Error message is :

```
meshlab: symbol lookup error: /home/eric/dev/3D/meshlab/meshlab/src/distrib/plugins/libfilter_screened_poisson.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs
```

This symbol is available in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0 :

```
$ objdump -T /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0|grep omp_get_num_procs
00000000000125c0 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  OMP_1.0     omp_get_num_procs_
0000000000011870 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  OMP_1.0     omp_get_num_procs
```

I am running meshlab from a GNOME terminal after having generated it. My LD_LIBRARY_PATH (and LIBDIR) is :

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
```

So I added /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu in LIBDIR

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

But now, I have this error :

```
$ ./meshlab
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".    
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.    
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

How to tell the plugin where to find the appropriate symbol ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting QT plugin path as follows:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/user/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/plugins
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't solve the issue. Adding /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu in LIBDIR creates a librairies dependancies issue with libqxcb.so. Command `$ ldd /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so` returns `/opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: version 'Qt_5_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so) /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.7' not found (required by /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so) ....`

Comment: Okay. You are getting exactly same errors as I was getting. The problem you have mentioned is because of QT version mismatch. You are trying to use QT from `/opt/Qt/5.7/` but gcc linker is trying to load QT from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. I solved this by removing any other QT libraries present in the system except for the one I am trying to use. Anyway, even after doing all these, I got the `omp_num_procs` undefined symbol error back. Finally it is resolved by adding `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp -D_USE_OMP` in the `general.pri` file.

Comment: I got the clue from make log, which was repeatedly printing `warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel` etc. So somehow, OpenMP was not getting properly linked. If this solves your problem, I'll update my answer.

Comment: It did not work for me. When I do `ldd plugins/libfilter_screened_poisson.so`, I don't see `libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1` and I have `libcommon.so.1 => not found`. I found a [pull request on gitHub](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/pull/55) with another way.  But, it did not work again.

Comment: It worked for me by adding also `-fopenmp` to `linux:QMAKE_LFLAGS` in `filter_screened_poisson.pro`.